Does leaking water damage 7-segment displays?

Does leaking water damage 7-segment displays, so that some of their LEDs can light up but others can't?
If yes, can a 7-segment display which has been so damaged be repaired?
If yes, how can it be repaired?

Look at the picture. In the lower 3-digit 7-segment display, the left two digits in red rectangles have the problem: some parts of them light up but the others don't.

I mean it is electronics, if there is short during its operation it will get damaged. post a pic of the situation for more information, without more info, there is no way anyone can help.

quite possible. repair depends on the damage that was caused.

This part of your picture shows significant discoloration, which makes me think about heat. (It could be something else, but heat comes to mind first.) So I'm not surprised here.


Yes.
Yes.
Disassembly and replace all affected parts.

It will however not be worth it. Order a new display and replace it.

Without more detail on the type of display and the nature / extent of the damage the only real answers can be:

Maybe
Maybe but probably not worth it
It depends on the damage and the display


Most components are washable when unpowered.
Water on a powered board results in electrolysis which corrodes exposed conductors: traces, component pins, solder, etc.
Once conductors are corroded, or water creates current paths in the circuit, other things may happen, like a voltage regulator outputting a much higher voltage if its feedback divider gets wet. In this case, it will kill every component downstream.
If high voltage is involved, current flowing through water can be high enough to cause unrepairable damage by burns or shorting high voltage to low voltage components.
Water inside pushbuttons will probably corrode the internal switch too.
Repairs are possible, depending on what was eaten away.
If your 7 segment display is multiplexed, so all the digits are driven from the same outputs, and only two digits have missing segments but these segments work on the other digits, then the issue is not the drivers but the 7 segment LED component or broken pins/traces/connections.

Water in and of itself is unlikely to damage those potted and sealed displays. They are washed in DI water during PCB manufacturing typically.
However water can damage the PCB if there is power applied while the water is present. This should be visible- traces will be corroded through. That can be repaired.
It's also possible the displays can just die over time if they are poorly made and/or they are run at too high a current.
The displays themselves are not realistically repairable. The 3-digit one is more standard than the other and you should be able to find a replacement if it actually is dead.

You said "However water can damage the PCB if there is power applied while the water is present. This should be visible- traces will be corroded through. That can be repaired." But the point is that I tested the 7-segment display by applying suitable current and voltage to it. The result is what I said in the original post: "In the lower 3-digit 7-segment display, the left two digits in red rectangles have the problem: some parts of them light up but the others don't."

Then the display is likely damaged, but water is not necessarily the cause, as I said.
